# URL routing/rewriting and compatibility with Nginx/Lighttpd

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx, url-routing, lighttpd

I'm writing a simple URL routing code based on using mod_rewrite to pass the URI as a GET parameter, like Drupal does. So I have the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And the URL http://www.example.com/test/1 would give me "/test/1/" passed as value $_GET['q'], instead of the usual index.php/test/1 and having to extract that from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

The thing is, the mod_rewrite QSA flag allows me to still use query strings normally, which I find very useful for parameters like filters and pagination, like "/products/category/?pg=1".

Will this work the same on Nginx and Lighttpd servers? I'd like my code to be portable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, in either case you'll have to translate your rules into each server's specific syntax. Some links to get you started:

- http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=187965
- http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Docs:ModRewrite
- https://serverfault.com/questions/24243/nginx-support-for-htaccess-rewrite-rules-differences-from-apache